# how would I access this selector using child/parent notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, selector

Hello how would I access the `text` object using the child parent css selector notation

[image]

ie   `$(#mydivID > svg)`  would get my svg object which has no class name or id.

how would I get the the `text` object? would it be `$(.x axis > g > text)` ? I'm not sure

I'm using d3 but jquery and d3 can get selectors using the similar notation and I figured more people would be familiar with jquery so they might answer the question adequately enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct CSS selector would be `.x.axis > g > text`.

**EDIT:** [ajp15243 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298394/how-would-i-access-this-selector-using-child-parent-notation/15298468#comment-21590510) that this would get all the `text` elements in `g` elements nested immediately below `.x.axis`. To get the *specific* `text` element highlighted above, use this selector:

`.x.axis > g:nth-child(2) > text`

Comment: @CQM Note if the first `<g>` tag inside of `.x.axis` also has an immediate child `<text>` tag, you will be selecting that as well. Given the answer's edit, however, that shouldn't be a problem :). It all depends on what you want.

Comment: @ajp15243 and Barney, this put me on the right track, I ended up selecting it like this `d3.select('.x.axis').selectAll('g > text')`

Comment: @CQM If that works, then great. Just be aware that if you add any other nested `<g>` tags anywhere under `.x.axis` with immediate `<text>` child tags, those will be selected too. If you don't do that, then it looks like you're good to go.